# How to get value from listview in c++

Tags: c++, listview, c++builder

I'm using C++ Builder 2010. I'm wondering, how can I get a value from ListView component? And is it possible get value only from 2-nd column(for instance). 
I found a lot of information about *adding* values to ListView, not *reading*.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListView.Items): "Use **Items** to directly access the **TListItem** objects that represent the items in the list. Setting this property at design time brings up the ListView Items Editor. Use this dialog to add or delete items or subitems, and to edit their display properties. At run time, use each item's **Caption**, **ImageIndex**, and **StateIndex** properties to change the appearance of the list items." You may also want to access **SubItems**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you *add* a new item, the `TListItems::Add()` method returns a `TListItem*`.  To access an *existing* item, you use the same `TListItems` to get a `TListItem*` for the desired item, eg:

```
// get the desired item by its index in the list...
TListItem *Item = ListView1->Items->Item[index];
```

In any given item, the 1st column is represented by the `TListItem::Caption` property, and subsequent columns are represented by the `TListItem::SubItems` property.  So, just like when *adding* values using `SubItems`, you use `SubItems` to read the values, eg:

```
String value = item->SubItems->Strings[0]; // 0 = 2nd column, 1 = 3rd column, etc...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is exactly what I needed!